# Get highest subvalues in a 3-dimensional array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [medium_priority] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [module] => a
                    [block] => b
                    [message] => c
                    [weight] => 60
                )

        )

    [high_priority] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [module] => a
                    [block] => b
                    [message] => c
                    [weight] => 95
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [module] => a
                    [block] => b
                    [message] => c
                    [weight] => 85
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [module] => a
                    [block] => b
                    [message] => c
                    [weight] => 80
                )

        )

    [low_priority] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [module] => a
                    [block] => b
                    [message] => c
                    [weight] => 20
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [module] => a
                    [block] => b
                    [message] => c
                    [weight] => 30
                )

        )

)
```

Using PHP, I want to get an array consisting of the five values with the highest `weight`, like this:

```
Array
(               
    [0] => Array
        (
            [module] => a
            [block] => b
            [message] => c
            [weight] => 95
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [module] => a
            [block] => b
            [message] => c
            [weight] => 85
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [module] => a
            [block] => b
            [message] => c
            [weight] => 80
        )               

    [3] => Array
        (
            [module] => a
            [block] => b
            [message] => c
            [weight] => 60
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [module] => a
            [block] => b
            [message] => c
            [weight] => 30
        )

)
```

Of course, this could be accomplished by iterating over the array using a loop to 'flatten' the array and then sort it `usort`, but I think there should be an easier and faster way.
However, I can't figure out what that would be.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Looks like a typical problem for `LINQ`. See http://phplinq.codeplex.com or http://plinq.codeplex.com.  `Disclosure:` I have little experience w/ PHP and none w/ these LINQ implementations (beware some seem a bit "young").  I'm just glad to see this type of features coming to more languages and abstracting out the more common programming tasks.

Comment: This seems a bit overkill for a rather simple problem, but still, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Agreed, if this the _only_ use of LINQ-like constructs you may have, but, assuming some LINQ libraries for PHP are stable enough, the investment for adding this feature to your PHP environment and for some possible "learning curve" should typically pay back for itself quickly.  There are so many instances where few lines of LINQ can replace long boilerplate code sections, making the program easier to read, but also faster to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-code:

1. Grab `array_values` from the original data set.
2. Use `array_merge` to combine them all (essentially flatten)
3. Use a usort and pop off first 5 elements